# Excel creating multiply conditions ranking

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, ranking, rank

I am trying to make a conditional ranking in this chart:

[image]
On the right you can see the total score and ranking from the `Match 1,2,3` (sum)
on line `A` and `C` I have a tie score (3 points and both ranked at 2nd place), I'd like to to add a 2nd and 3rd conditions to determinate the final ranking.
If there is a tie in score (both are in same ranking), then to determine who is 2nd and who is 3rd place I want to use the values from the `XX's` column first. The higher value will win the 2nd place and in a case there is still a tie (as both are the same value of 0), it will continue and check the value on the `X's` column and since line `C` = 27 and line `A` = 21, line `C` will be ranked as 2nd place and line `A` will be ranked as 3rd place.
Also will like to add an option to continue with 3 condition if there is still a tie.

I am using a simple ranks formula `=RANK(AK7,$AK$7:$AK$10)` to determine the rank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple 'math' solution: do a linear combination with weights.
Do something like

```
Wscore = 1000*Score + 10*XXvalue + Xvalue
```

then sort values using simple rank function.

Just change weights according to your values distribution, if needed.